# Spring Boot (Batch) - Inject Datasource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Boot (batch-oriented) application that uses a datasource in order to finalize a batch job and write stuff to the database.

I have the datasource(s) defined inside the `application.yml` like:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:JavaSpringBootBatch
    username: sa
    password:
  profiles: # default, development, production
    active: default, development
---
spring:
  h2:
    # ...config/settings here
  profiles: development
---
spring:
  datasource:
    # ...datasource config here
  profiles: production
```

The issue is when I try to inject the datasource into one of the Spring config files:

```
@Configuration
public class PlayerBatchConfig {
  ...

  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<Player> writer(final DataSource dataSource) {
    final JdbcBatchItemWriter<Player> jdbcItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    ...
    jdbcItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcItemWriter.setSql(sql.toString());
    return jdbcItemWriter;
  }
}
```

...it tells me that:

> Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'DataSource' type.
>
> Beans:
>   dataSource (DataSourceConfiguration.class)
>   dataSource (EmbeddedDataSourceConfiguration.class)

I also tried to inject the datasource like:

```
@Configuration
public class PlayerBatchConfig {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  ...
}
```

...but no luck :( , although the issue with the two datasources goes away eventually.

Any clues how to "circumvent" that?

Comment: i think "spring.h2.console.enabled=true" and "spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console" enables h2 database and you have defined another datasource explicitly again and both are for "development" profile. Thus container seeing as multiple datasource.

Comment: Not quite just those, but the actual definition on the `default` profile chunk. That only let you access the H2 console on when `development` is used by browsing `http://.../h2-console`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 2 datasources you need the annotate them with the @Qualifier the datasources bean and when you use them as well. Spring is telling you it doesn't know which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSource` which you want to use `annotate` it with `@Primary`, refer spring-boot documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources) for further info. Along with `@Primary` you might also need to use `@Qualifier` for controlling the bean injection.

Comment: Like I stated, the issue is that I wouldn't like to go back and configure the datasource(s) in the Java config; I would like to keep them in the YAML file. Anyway, I have it like that for now since I can't find a way to make it work so far, but yes, if I do it with the Java config is somewhat easy...